# How to free up all used RAM in a C# process?

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

*Yet another question about Garbarge Collector. There are many questions and few clear answers about the behavior of the garbage collector in the .net environment. My question is simple and I hope that if someone can answer it clearly that should help a lot of people who will pass by here.*

So, here is a simple code (.net core 6.0.101)

```cs
var arraySize = int.MaxValue / 4;
var rnd = new Random();
var arrays = new List<byte[]>();

// Initial memory footprint
Console.WriteLine($"[0] Memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1000000:N0} MB");
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    var array = new byte[arraySize];
    // fill the array to be sure that .net doesn't do obscure memory optimizations
    rnd.NextBytes(array);
    arrays.Add(array);
}

Console.WriteLine($"[Before GC] Memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1000000:N0} MB");

arrays.Clear();
arrays = null;

GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Console.WriteLine($"[After GC] Memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1000000:N0} MB");

Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

And now the result.

```sh
C:\testsgc>dotnet run
[0] Memory: 0 MB
[Before GC] Memory: 2 147 MB
[After GC] Memory: 536 MB
Press a key to exit
```

Process memory footprint (Task Manager):

- Initial memory : 5,6 MB
- After filling variables : 2 056,5 MB
- After Garbage Collection : 520,1 MB

At startup, the process takes 5,6 MB or RAM. One array of bytes takes around 500 MB of ram. The list is cleared and assigned to null (not required).

So the question is, how to free up the last array of bytes?

Only a **precise** and **verifiable** answer will be marked as resolved.

Comment: Try running another `GC.Collect` after `WaitForPendingFinalizers`. Also, make sure you're not running with a debugger attached and that you built for Release and not for Debug. Variables are artificially prolonged in scope lifetime to support hitting breakpoints after a variable was last used and still be able to inspect it, so for instance the `array` variable in your loop might linger around until the end of the method.

Comment: Thanks trying to help @LasseV.Karlsen !
Unfortunately, I can confirm that the program was running without any debugger attached and I also tried to run `GC.Collect` after `WaitForPendingFinalizers` without any success. I even tried a for loop or 100 iterations of GC.Collect.

Comment: I cannot tell you exactly why that is, but you're keeping 1 of those 5 arrays in memory when you run your final report. Adding an additional GC.Collect does not help, but running in Release build does. Most likely this is the artificial lifetime extension I mentioned in my other comment that is in play here. However, even setting `array` to `null` inside the loop does not change this for Debug builds. As such I am unable to explain why the array is still in memory. However, adding one of those Console.WriteLine calls just after `var array = new` shows the exact same memory usage.

Comment: Try `dotnet run --configuration Release`

Comment: configuration Release did the job !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your sub-arrays are still kept in memory when you run the program from a Debug build.

Let's adjust your program just slightly, add a `Console.WriteLine` inside your loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    var array = new byte[arraySize];
    Console.WriteLine($"[In loop] Memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1000000:N0} MB");
```

the output of your program now becomes:

```
> dotnet run
[0] Memory: 0 MB
[In loop] Memory: 536 MB
[In loop] Memory: 1 073 MB
[In loop] Memory: 1 610 MB
[In loop] Memory: 2 147 MB
[Before GC] Memory: 2 147 MB
[After GC] Memory: 536 MB
```

As you can see, the first report from the loop matches in size. So most likely one of the arrays have survived garbage collection.

A typical way to "fix this" is to add another call to `GC.Collect` after a call to `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers`, but this makes no difference here.

Variables that are no longer used are in fact eligible for garbage collection, but only if you do not run using a debugger and have compiled with optimizations enabled, aka Release-build.

So if we try to just run the program from a Release-build instead:

```
> dotnet run --configuration Release
[0] Memory: 0 MB
[Before GC] Memory: 2 147 MB
[After GC] Memory: 0 MB
```

While I cannot explain why one of the sub-arrays was still alive and kicking, it seems to be related. I tried setting `array` to `null` inside the loop, after adding it to the `arrays` list, but this did not change anything.